# Can't Figure out the Syntax Error in App.js

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework

I am using this tutorial to install React for the front with an API built in Django.

https://sweetcode.io/how-use-djang-react-ap/

My repository for this projects so far is here:

https://github.com/AlexMercedCoder/DjangoReactCRM

When I npm run dev I get a syntax error in App.js, I've played with it and can't seem to figure it out. The error I get is.

```
ERROR in ./frontend/src/components/App.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: 
C:\Users\alexm\projects\DjangoReactCRM\drcrm\frontend\src
\components\App.js: Unexpected token, expected "," (29:6)

  27 |
  28 | wrapper ? ReactDOM.render(<app>, wrapper) : null;
> 29 | </app>
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";


class App extends Component {

  state = {
      data: ''
  };

    componentDidMount() {
       fetch("/api")
          .then(response => {
           return response.json();
        })
        .then(data => this.setState({ data: JSON.stringify(data)}));
  }

   render(){

      return (
            <p>Jason data = {this.state.data}</p>
      )
  }
}


wrapper ? ReactDOM.render(<app>, wrapper) : null;
</app>
```

Comment: What is `</app>` doing at the end of the file?

Comment: React components are **always** capitalized, try `<App />` instead. `wrapper` seems to be undefined in your snippet, or it isn't clear where it is defined. And yes, you seem to have some random JSX at the end of your file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the `<app>` component is closed outside the ternary operator, so you'd have to use `<app></ app>` or even simpler `<app />`.

```
wrapper ? ReactDOM.render(<app></app>, wrapper) : null;
```

or

```
wrapper ? ReactDOM.render(<app/>, wrapper) : null;
```

Then, all React components must start with a capital letter 
to differentiate default DOM component from those created with React, so you have to use this notation.

```
wrapper ? ReactDOM.render(<App />, wrapper) : null;
```

Finally, I do not see the utility of the ternary operator at the end of your code. Normally, the second argument when we call `reactDOM.render(X, Y)` must represent the DOM element in which we will render our main React component (in this case, `<App />`).

By default, when we create a React project with `create-react-app`, we don't have to deal with these settings and the DOM element is automatically defined as `<div id='root'></div>` (check inside the `<body>` in `public/index.html` inside your project root).
So call `document.getElementById('root')` to get the DOM element and simply put the result as second argument.

```
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

If it persist, I suggest you to simply create another React project with create-react-app and copy/paste only the code you need.

To get more informations: [Click here](https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html)

I hope it can help you.

** I apologize if my explanations are not clear or if I made some mistakes.

Comment: Will make those changes, that last line is straight from the tutorial . Didn’t make sense to me for some of reasons mentioned but the tutorial is implementing React within django so I figured it may be needed for Django to start up React.

(The tutorial is to run React within django instead of separately on different ports) I’m comfortable with us create-React-app, this was a bit more involved.

Will report back in this worked soon.

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much for the help, I can now proceed designing the front end of the project!

Answer (score 2):

There are three problems in your component.

1. I'm guessing `wrapper` was supposed to be `document.getElementById("root")` ? Even then the ternary condition doesn't make sense. It should be something like:

```
ReactDOM.render(
 <App />,
document.getElementById("root")
)
```

2. You defined the component as `App`, yet in `ReactDOM.render` you are using `app`
3. You have `</app>` at the end of the file. It doesn't do anything in this case.